# Conserved charge of non-holomorphic currents in 2d CFT

Tags: symmetry, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, noethers-theorem

A conserved current in a 2d CFT satisfy
$$ \overline{\partial}j_{z} + \partial j_{\overline{z}} = 0, $$
where $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are the usual complex coordinates of the Euclidean conformal field theory. In eq. (2.4) of ref. [1], the associated conserved charge is defined as
$$Q \equiv \oint\limits_{|z|=R} \frac{\text{d}z}{z}j^{t}(z)=\oint\limits_{|z|=R} \text{d}z \bigg(j_z(z)+\frac{\bar{z}}{z}j_{\bar{z}}(z)\bigg)\, \tag{2.4} $$

where $j^{t}$ is the time component of the current. Now, in the $( x,\tau )$ coordinates, the contour integral in (2.4) would be an integral over $x$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$, where $x= \tfrac{1}{2}(z + \overline{z})$ so that $dx = \tfrac{1}{2} (dz + d \overline{z})$, therefore, shouldn't we have an integral over $\overline{z}$ in the left-hand-side of (2.4) also? Basically, I don't understand what is the justification for eq. (2.4) being the right definition for the conserved charge.

---

[1] L. Eberhardt and K. Ferreira, *The plane-wave spectrum from the worldsheet*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.12155.